# Elasticsearch 2.1.0

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Elasticsearch version 2.1.0 is not connecting to kibana 4.3. I'm seeing failed to delete temp file error

```
[2015-12-10 08:20:30,891][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Mass Master] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2015-12-10 08:20:31,219][WARN ][index.ny ranslog           ] [Mass Master] [.kibana][0] failed to delete temp file /home/ec2-user/elasticsearch-2.1.0/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.kibana/0/translog/translog-6795115948573540946.tlog
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/ec2-user/elasticsearch-2.1.0/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/.kibana/0/translog/translog-6795115948573540946.tlog
```

Referred this link https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/14872 not able to get it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add information: 0) which OS are you using 1) how did you install kibana 2) how you start it. From first view it is a permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using kibana and elasticsearch of same versions. E.g. kibana 4.3 for ES 4.3. Version incompatibility might be an issue in your case.